# Removing cart products from input with product id value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento-1.9

I wanted to work with `input type ="hidden"` so I can do a check. I have a slider which displays products of a category and through two Ajax requests I add and remove them through clicks on buy and remove buttons, however that does not have as much relevance in this question.

Only one such product on the slide can be purchased by order, but if one of them is added and the page is updated and the buy button is clicked again, another of that product is added, which should not happen. I wanted to make sure that in the update of the page, if there is already one of these products added, it is removed, but I do not know where to follow it to complete it.I think I should use an `input type ="hidden"`, so that through it I can save the value of the id of the added product, but I do not know how to do this verification.

Below I will add the code of the buttons and the input that I have already made and are correct, besides the code of the Ajax requisitions. If necessary, I add the code of the controllers I use.

**Button and input code:**

```
<button style="margin-left: 11%;" type="button"  class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<button style="display: none; margin-left: 11%;" type="button" id="cartaoMensagemRemover<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" title="Remover" class="button btn-cart" onclick="removeCartaotoCart('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span>Remove</span></span></button>
<input type="hidden" name="cartao_adicionado" id="cartao_adicionado" value="" />
```

**Ajax requisition code:**

```
var productSelected = "";

        function addCartao(product){
            if( productSelected != "" ){
                removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);    // Remove the item in cart, if there is one.
              }
            $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product).hide();
            $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product).show();
            $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product).css({'background-color': '#000000'});
            $j.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao') ?>",
              data: {
                product: product
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              cache : false,
              beforeSend: function () {

              },
              success: function (retorno) {
                var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product);
                productSelected = product;

                $j('#cartaoMensagemAdicionado').val(productSelected);                   
                $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend'+product+'"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
                getSubTotal();
                getGrandTotal();
              },
              complete: function () {

              },
              error: function (x,y,z) {
                alert("error");
                alert(x);
                alert(y);
                alert(z);
              }
          });
        }

        function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
            productSelected = ""; 
            $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
            $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
            $j.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/removeCartao') ?>",
                data:{
                    itemId: itemId
                },
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){

                },
                success: function(retorno){
                    var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);
                    $j('#cartaoMensagemAdicionado').val(productSelected);                        
                    $j('.item-custom #trAppend'+itemId+'').remove();
                    getSubTotal();
                    getGrandTotal();                       
                },
                complete: function () {

                },
                error: function (x,y,z) {
                alert("error");
                alert(x);
                alert(y);
                alert(z);
              }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is make a small php code to do the verification, where it contains the SKUs of these products and if they are in the cart, assign a value to a boolean variable and insert it into an `input` to work this value in jQuery.

**Php code for verification:**

```
<?php
    $array_de_skus_de_cartoes = array(45,60,80,90,102,103,104,105); //SKUs of products
    $isCartaoAdicionado = 0;
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {

        foreach ($array_de_skus_de_cartoes as $sku) {
            if($sku == $item->getProduct()->getSku()) {
                $isCartaoAdicionado = 1;
                $cartao_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($sku);
            }
        }
    }

    if($isCartaoAdicionado == 1) {
?>
        <input type="hidden" name="cartao_adicionado" id="cartao_adicionado" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cartao_adicionado_product_id" id="cartao_adicionado_product_id"" value="<?php echo $cartao_id ?>" />
<?php
    }
    else {
?>
        <input type="hidden" name="cartao_adicionado" id="cartao_adicionado" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cartao_adicionado_product_id" id="cartao_adicionado_product_id"" value="" />
<?php
    }
?>
```

**Ajax request code updated:**

```
    var isCartaoAdicionado = $j('#cartao_adicionado').val();
    var isCartaoAdicionadoProductId = $j('#cartao_adicionado_product_id').val();
    var productSelected = "";

    function addCartao(product){
        if(isCartaoAdicionado == 1){
            removeCartaotoCart(isCartaoAdicionadoProductId);
        }
        if( productSelected != "" ){
            removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);    // Remove the item in cart, if there is one.
        }
        $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product).hide();
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product).show();
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product).css({'background-color': '#000000'});
        $j.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao') ?>",
          data: {
            product: product
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache : false,
          beforeSend: function () {

          },
          success: function (retorno) {
            var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product);
            productSelected = product;
            $j('#cartaoMensagemAdicionado'+product).val(productSelected);            
            $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend'+product+'"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
            getSubTotal();
            getGrandTotal();
          },
          complete: function () {

          },
          error: function (x,y,z) {
            alert("error");
            alert(x);
            alert(y);
            alert(z);
          }
      });
    }

    function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
        productSelected = ""; 
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
        $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
        $j.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/removeCartao') ?>",
            data:{
                itemId: itemId
            },
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(retorno){
                var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);                $j('#cartaoMensagemAdicionado'+itemId).val(productSelected);
                $j('.item-custom #trAppend'+itemId+'').remove();
                getSubTotal();
                getGrandTotal();
            },
            complete: function () {

            },
            error: function (x,y,z) {
            alert("error");
            alert(x);
            alert(y);
            alert(z);
          }
        });
    }
```